# Do we need multiple-entry visa for Australia if only transiting airport on the second entry?

Tags: visas, transit, australia, filipino-citizens

Do we need a multiple-entry visa for Australia if I hold a Philippine passport traveling to Melbourne, Australia (1st entry) for 3 days and then fly to New Zealand (with NZ tourist visa too) for 3 days. Then our return trip to Philippines will transit Australia, so we're flying back from New Zealand to Australia, I assumed that this would count as our second entry to Australia?

Do we need a multiple entry Australian tourist visa or we just need a transit visa in Australia for an XX hours in transit?

Comment: What airport are you flying through on the way back to the Philippines?

Comment: Are the two flights on a single ticket (which would allow you to check your luggage through and may not need a visa if you can stay airside ) or on separate tickets (which means you need to go through passport control, reclaim bags, go through customs and check back in, which requires a visa/visa entry)?

Answer (score 4):

A Philippine national doesn't need a visa to transit Sydney airside for a layover of 8 hours or less, according to Timatic, which is the database airlines use to verify passengers' travel documents.

> Visa required, except for Nationals of Philippines transiting through Perth (PER) with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 8 hours. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.
>
> - TWOV does not apply when transiting between T1/T2 and T3/T4 at Perth (PER).
>
> Visa required, except for Nationals of Philippines transiting through Cairns (CNS) or Sydney (SYD) with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 8 hours on the same calendar day. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.
>
> Visa required, except for Nationals of Philippines transiting through Adelaide (ADL) with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 8 hours on the same calendar day. When transiting on different aircraft, the airline must give advance notice. They must have documents required for the next destination.
>
> Visa required, except for Nationals of Philippines transiting through Gold Coast (OOL) with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 2 hours or arriving and departing on the same aircraft. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.
>
> Visa required, except for Nationals of Philippines transiting through Brisbane (BNE), Darwin (DRW) or Melbourne (MEL) with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 8 hours. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.

So a single entry visa will be fine for visiting Australia before going to New Zealand, and then no visa is needed for the return transit. But you can still apply for a multiple entry visa; you just might get it anyway.

Comment: The OP said they're flying via Melbourne on the way in...

Comment: Also this is valid only if luggage is checked through (both flights on the same ticket).

Comment: @jpatokal And didn't mention which airport on the return flight, thanks for catching that.

Comment: @jptokal hi, our entry & exit is on Melbourne Tullamarine airport

Comment: @jcaron, unfortunately separate tickets for (PHP <> OZ ) & (OZ <> NZ).

Comment: @Michael Hampton, thank you for the info this is very helpful.

Comment: my understanding is we're good to go with single entry right?

Comment: @Pei With separate tickets you may have to clear immigration anyway to transfer your baggage. You should get a multiple entry visa.

Comment: @Pei unless the two tickets are on partner airlines and you can convince them to do through check-in (which is often a bit of a lottery), then you'll have to go through passport control to reclaim your bags and check them in again, so you'll need a valid visa for that entry (i.e. a multiple entry visa in your case). You also need to have enough time to do all that before the check-in deadline, even if your first flight is late. Remember that if you don't make the check-in/baggage drop deadline, you'll be considered a no show, and will have to rebook (and pay for) a new ticket.

Comment: @MichaelHampton yes, I do think so too we really need a multiple visa, and as for PH passport holder it's not easy. But anyway thank you so much for all your response guys.  It really helps to plan our trip. Salamat po!

Comment: @jcaron, sad to say our tickets are not from partner airlines, so we really need to get a multiple visa. :( . Crossing our fingers to be granted multiple visa. Thank you for  taking time and patiently answering my queries. Thanks a bunch! :)